# When user creates folders they aren't created on the NAS

Tags: windows-7, windows-sbs-2011

I've got a peculiar problem with one of my users. Often when the user creates folders on the NAS, she can see the folders on her own workstation. She can also access and browse these folders, but she can't create files or save files in these folders. If I log on to any other workstation, I can't see these folders at all - they don't exist.

Does anyone have any clue on what is going on and how I solve this? I've tried to remove the machine from Windows AD and recreate the user credentials. It helps for a while but eventually the problem occurs again.

Server:    Windows SBS 2011

NAS:       Qnap TS-412U

Workstation: HP ProBook 6570b / Windows 7

/Carl

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked "offline folders" are enabled for this share ? If yes, has she clicked "Always available offline" on the share ?

Also, are there special characters in the folder names she uses ?